# R scrape html table and extract background color

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape some data off a wikipedia table from this page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Results_of_the_Indian_general_election,_2014 and I am interested in the table:
Summary of the 2014 Indian general election

I would also like to extract the party colors from the table. 
Here's what I've tried so far:

```
library("rvest")
url <- 
"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Results_of_the_Indian_general_election,_2014"

electionstats <- read_html(url)
results <- html_nodes(electionstats, xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[79]') %>% html_table(fill = T)

party_colors <- electionstats %>% 
html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[3]') %>% 
html_table(fill = T)
```

Printing out party_colors does not show any info about the colors

So, I tried:

```
party_colors <- electionstats %>% html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[3]') %>%  
html_nodes('tr')
```

Now if I print out party_colors, I get:

```
[1] <tr style="background-color:#E9E9E9">\n<th style="text-align:left;vertical-align:bottom;" rowspan="2"></th>\n<th style="text-align:left; ...
[2] <tr style="background-color:#E9E9E9">\n<th style="text-align:center;">No.</th>\n<th style="text-align:center;">+/-</th>\n<th style="text ...
[3] <tr>\n<td style="background-color:#FF9933"></td>\n<td style="text-align:left;"><a href="/wiki/Bharatiya_Janata_Party" title="Bharatiya J ...
[4] <tr>\n<td style="background-color:#00BFFF"></td>\n<td style="text-align:left;"><a href="/wiki/Indian_National_Congress" title="Indian Na ...
[5] <tr>\n<td style="background-color:#009900"></td>\n<td style="text-align:left;"><a href="/wiki/All_India_Anna_Dravida_Munnetra_Kazhagam"  ...
```

and so on...

But, now, I have no idea how to pull out the colors from this data. I cannot convert the output of the above to a html_table with:

```
html_table(fill = T)
```

I get the error:

```
Error: html_name(x) == "table" is not TRUE
```

I also tried various options with html_attrs, but I have no idea what the correct attribute I should be passing is.

I even tried SelectorGadget to try and figure out the attribute, but if I select the first column of the table in question, SelectorGadget shows just "td".

Comment: FWIW, I can't reproduce your code: `results` is an empty list. I'm wondering if this is down to the XPath. It seems like selecting a table on a Wikipedia page without an `id` isnot super reproducible, but I guess you don't really have a choice :/

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out .... when beautifying the entry, I inadvertently deleted a hyphen in the xpath. Fixed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would get the table like you did and then add the color attribute as a column.  The wikitable sortable class works on many pages, so get the first one and remove the second header in row 1.

```
electionstats <- read_html(url) 
x <- html_nodes(electionstats, xpath='//table[@class="wikitable sortable"]')[[1]] %>% 
      html_table(fill=TRUE)
# paste names from 2nd row header and then remove
names(x)[6:14] <- paste(names(x)[6:14], x[1,6:14])
x <- x[-1,]
```

The colors are in the first `tr/td` tags and you can add it to empty column 1 or 3 (see `str(x)`)

```
names(x)[3] <- "Color"
x$Color <- html_nodes(electionstats, xpath='//table[@class="wikitable sortable"][1]/tr/td[1]') %>% 
            html_attr("style") %>% gsub("background-color:", "", .)
## drop table footer, extra columns
x <- x[1:83, 2:14]   
head(x)
                                     Party   Color Alliance Abbr. Candidates No. Candidates +/- Candidates %
2                   Bharatiya Janata Party #FF9933      NDA   BJP            428             -5       78.82%
3                 Indian National Congress #00BFFF      UPA   INC            464             24       85.45%
4 All India Anna Dravida Munnetra Kazhagam #009900           ADMK             40             17        7.37%
5             All India Trinamool Congress #00FF00           AITC            131             96       24.13%
6                          Biju Janata Dal #006400            BJD             21              3        3.87%
7                                Shiv Sena #E3882D      NDA   SHS             24             11       10.68%
```

Comment: I guess the /tr/td[1] in xpath='//table[@class="wikitable sortable"][1]/tr/td[1]  is what I was looking for. This works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your **xml_nodeset** contains *both* **tr** and **td** nodes.

**Deal with both trs and tds, converting to data frames:**

```
party_colors_tr <- electionstats %>% html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[3]') %>% html_nodes('tr')
trs <- bind_rows(lapply(xml_attrs(party_colors_tr), function(x) data.frame(as.list(x), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)))
party_colors_td <- electionstats %>% html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[3]') %>% html_nodes('tr') %>% html_nodes('td')
tds <- bind_rows(lapply(xml_attrs(party_colors_td), function(x) data.frame(as.list(x), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)))
```

**Write function for extracting styles from data frames:**

```
library(stringi)
list_styles <- function(nodes_frame) {
    get_cols <- function(x) { stri_detect_fixed(x, 'background-color') }
    has_style <- which(lapply(nodes_frame$style, get_cols) == TRUE)
    res <- strsplit(nodes_frame[has_style,]$style, ':')
    return(res)
}
```

**Create data frame of extracted styles:**

```
l_trs <- list_styles(trs)
df_trs <- data.frame(do.call('rbind', l_trs)[,1], do.call('rbind', l_trs)[,2])
names(df_trs) <- c('style', 'color')

l_tds <- list_styles(tds)
df_tds <- data.frame(do.call('rbind', l_tds)[,1], do.call('rbind', l_tds)[,2])
names(df_tds) <- c('style', 'color')
```

**Combine trs and tds frames:**

```
final_style_frame <- do.call('rbind', list(df_trs, df_tds))
```

**Here are the first 20 rows:**

```
final_style_frame[1:20,]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! And here I was convinced that R is so easy :) Nevertheless, good to have a solution. Is this the most efficient way to achieve what I want? Are there other packages/approaches?

Comment: Definitely not the most efficient way. I’ll let you know if I find something better.